# Corrected an answer - what should I do about the comments that prompted the edit?

Tags: discussion, comments

I posted [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578038/hard-disk-free-space-going-down) that unfortunately contained a couple of minor errors.

These were pointed out in comments, and I edited the answer to correct it.

However, this now means that the comments that say there's a mistake are actually incorrect.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post a comment below those comment that you added it into the answer. The users will see this comment and might remove theirs. If they don't everyone else can see you saw their comments and acted upon them.

Besides that: most of us can see your answer was edited and what was edited. So we can all see the comments became obsolete ;)

Comment: @carl-h: Don't feel bad!  The entire site is riddled with these comments, even from very high ranking users...

Comment: You can also flag the comments as obsolete. (maybe you should *cough* edit that into your answer? *cough*)